# Get the output from the list c#

Tags: c#, list

In a list similar to this:
`

```
public static List<Items> Models()
        {
        List<Items> listOfModels = new List<Items>()
            {
         new Items() {
        ModelID="M10",
        ModelNames = new List<string>() {"model1","model2"}},
         new Items() {
        ModelID="M20",
        ModelName = new List<string>(){"model3","model4","model5"}}
            };
           return listOfModels;
        }
```

`

How to get the following output?
(model1,m10)
(model2,m10)
(model3,m20)
(model4,m20)
(model5,m20)

`var allModels = Models().SelectMany(c => c.ModelName)`

output : model , model2, model3,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a small update of your code:

```
var allModels = Models()
    .SelectMany(item => item.ModelName.Select(model => $"({model},{item.ModelID})"));
```

then print models :

```
foreach(var model in allModels)
{
    Console.WriteLine(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var models = Models().SelectMany(c => c.ModelNames.Select(n => $"({n},{c.ModelID})")).ToList();
```